# Press and hold arrow keys to scroll in grid in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll, dom-events

Take the following React (17.0.2) component:

```
const Grid = () => {
     return (
          <div id='grid' style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
               <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                   <div>
                       1
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       2
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       3
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                   <div>
                       4
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       5
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       6
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                   <div>
                       7
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       8
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       9
                   </div>
               </div>
          </div>

     )
}
```

It's just a simple grid with some simple data. It's easy enough to add event listeners to it that allow you to scroll with arrow keys if you tap them. How do I make it so holding down the arrow keys will scroll continually?

The main thing I've tried to far is:

1. Save the selected cell in React state.
2. On a keydown event, set an interval that that moves the selected cell in the right direction.
3. When the keyup event, clear this interval

This suffers from the problem that it is really inconsistent - the interval is only sometimes cleared and sometimes scrolling just continues!

Bonus points if you can make the grid bigger, and then keep the element that is scrolled in the viewport!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which react version are you using? It'll helps us can put a suggestion code more effective

Comment: @RobertCorponoi updated with what I've tried so far.

Comment: @hai-thai updated with react version at the top also!

Answer (score 2):

Just simple with this - use ref to handle current element focus and user press keydown

```js
const myRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    const node = myRef.current;
    node.addEventListener('keydown',(e) => {
      const active = document.activeElement;
      if(e.keyCode === 40 && active.nextSibling) {
        active.nextSibling.focus();
      }
      if(e.keyCode === 38 && active.previousSibling) {
        active.previousSibling.focus();
      }
    });

} , [])

<div id='grid' ref={myRef} style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
```

Comment: Cool! So what I was missing is just that a keydown event gets repeatedly triggered if you hold the key down. Helpful. Thank you!